# JMeter - JSR223 get current time in milliseconds

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to calculate SSE traffic latency in a simple load test using the following JSR223 Sampler:

```
EventHandler eventHandler = eventText -> {
  count++;
  // get the time from the server
  def result = eventText.substring(eventText.indexOf("data='") + 6, eventText.indexOf("', event")).trim() as Long;  
  def currenTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  def diff = currenTime - result;
  list.add (diff);
  resp = resp + "Time from server:" + result + ", JMeter time:" + currenTime + ", diff:"+ diff +"\n";  
};

SSEClient sseClient = SSEClient.builder().url(pURL).eventHandler(eventHandler).build();
      
sseClient.start();

sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

sseClient.shutdown();
```

The time from the server (NodeJS -JavaScript) is `Date.now()` and the time on JMeter is `System.currentTimeMillis()`

**Both Server and JMeter are on the same computer.**

It seems that the time methods are not aligned as I can see that in some cases the JMeter time is earlier than the server time:

[image]

So I cannot trust the results...

Any other methods I should use on the JavaScript side or the JMeter side?

Comment: Can you check with ${__time(,)} function in JMeter side.

Comment: ${__time(,)} get the time when the sample starts and not the current time, so the value is the same throughout the life of the sample.

Comment: Uncheck Cache compiled script if available under Script Compilation Section and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trust the results in any case because having the system under test and the load generator on the same machine is not the best idea, you won't get reliable results due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Moreover it will be much harder to analyze the bottlenecks even with [PerfMon Plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Also as per [System.currentTimeMillis() function JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()):

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the **granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds**.

So if you want to measure the time difference between previous and next SSE you can consider using [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

However it's better to move JMeter to another machine and preferably a [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) as the precision of System.currentTimeMillis() function there is much higher